# Max within groups in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, max

I have the following matrix:

```
[ 2 5 7 8  1 3 4 6  5 7 3 1;
  1 1 1 1  2 2 2 2  3 3 3 3;]
```

The first row represents values and the second characteristic

I want to get the max value if the value in the second row is the same, i.e. their characteristic is the same. So, what I would like to have is:

`[ 8 6 7]`, since `8` is the highest value when the second row is `1`, `6` when the second row is is `2`, and `7` when the second row is `3`. I can do it with a loop, but I would like vectorized solution, and if possible of course, in one line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`accumarray` does exactly what you want

```
x=[ 2 5 7 8 1 3 4 6 5 7 3 1; 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3;]
accumarray(x(2,:)',x(1,:)',[],@max)
```

Comment: @ Daniel Thanks, I was not aware of it!

Comment: `accumarray`! Nice. +1